# Product Information: General: How to make measurements starred items (*)?

Tags: product

These items are starred in the general tab:

SKU *
Weight *

How do we make the following items "starred"/required? 
Width
Length
Height

Answer (score 2):

Edit the attributes in the backend `Catalog->Attributes->Manage attributes` and set the field `Required` to `Yes`.

Comment: I was hoping this would ensure that magento would upload these fields from our POS program. For some reason it uploads all other information (including weight) but will not upload width, length & height. Any suggestions?